# Using JSON in python

Tags: python, json

Hello i am wondering how i can get from json data like in matrix?  for better explenation:

```
{
     "00": "Echo reply",
     "03":{ "00" : "Destination Unreachable - Net Unreachable",
          "01" : "Destination Unreachable - Host Unreachable",
          "02" : "Destination Unreachable - Protocol Unreachable",
          "03" : "Destination Unreachable - Port Unreachable",
          "04" : "Destination Unreachable - Fragmentation Needed & DF Set",
          "05" : "Destination Unreachable - Source Route Failed",
          "06" : "Destination Unreachable - Destination Network Unknown",
          "07" : "Destination Unreachable - Destination Host unknown",
          "08" : "Destination Unreachable - Source Host Isolated",
          "09" : "Destination Unreachable - Network Administratively Prohibited",
          "0a" : "Destination Unreachable - Host Administratively Prohibited",
          "0b" : "Destination Unreachable - Network unreachable for TOS",
          "0c" : "Destination Unreachable - Host unreachable for TOS",
          "0d" : "Destination Unreachable - Communication Administratively Prohibited"
     },
     "04": "Source Quench",
     "05": {
          "00": "Redirect - Datagram for the Network",
          "01": "Redirect - Datagram for the Host",
          "02": "Redirect - Datagram for the TOS & Network",
          "03": "Redirect - Datagram for the TOS & Host"
     },
     "08": "Echo",
     "09": "Router Advertisement",
     "0a": "Router Selection",
     "0b": {
          "01":"Time Exceeded - Time to live exceeded in Transit",
          "02":"Time Exceeded - Fragment Reassembly Time Exceeded"
     },
     "0c": {
         "00": "Parameter Problem - Pointer indicates the error",
          "01": "Parameter Problem - Missing a Required Option",
          "02": "Parameter Problem - Bad Length"
     },
     "0d": "Timestamp",
     "0e": "Timestamp Reply",
     "0f": "Information Request",
     "10": "Information Reply",
     "11": "Address Mask Request",
     "12": "Address Mask Reply",
     "1e": "Traceroute"

}
```

This is my json File an i want to get from that "03" - > "00" but, idk how to get there

```
 f = open('icmp.json', )
 data = json.load(f)

 print(data[type, code])  #i was also trying data[type[code]] or data[type][code]
```

But not woriking for me ? :D please help

Comment: Do you mean `data['03']['00']`?

Comment: Yes i want to get that data :D but it´s not woriking for me

Comment: What does `print(data)` show?  Do you see the full data?  What about `print(data['03'])`?

Comment: How is RJAdriaansen's suggestion not working? You could put that exact string into your code and see. It worked for me. If it fails for you, update your example with the error traceback message.

Comment: Check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-between-json-load-and-json-loads/

Comment: print(type)  #08
    print(code) #00 
Iam sorry that exact is working

Comment: okey I see the problem, not every had that second opinion: for example 00: has nothing at that second position so its problem for my program

Comment: It would help to have a working example. `type` and `code` are not defined in your example. When you say `print(type)` results in `#08`... what was that? You could `print(repr(type))` and post exactly what was printed. It will show the difference between strings and integers. And if this is in a loop that works sometimes, but not other times, that is an important part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

when you load a json, it is a dictionary in python. you can get your item like this:

```
 f = open('icmp.json', )
 data = json.load(f)
 print(data['03']['00'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my json file to this worked :) Thx all for your response

```
{
     "00": {"00": "Echo reply" },
     "03":{ "00" : "Destination Unreachable - Net Unreachable",
          "01" : "Destination Unreachable - Host Unreachable",
          "02" : "Destination Unreachable - Protocol Unreachable",
          "03" : "Destination Unreachable - Port Unreachable",
          "04" : "Destination Unreachable - Fragmentation Needed & DF Set",
          "05" : "Destination Unreachable - Source Route Failed",
          "06" : "Destination Unreachable - Destination Network Unknown",
          "07" : "Destination Unreachable - Destination Host unknown",
          "08" : "Destination Unreachable - Source Host Isolated",
          "09" : "Destination Unreachable - Network Administratively Prohibited",
          "0a" : "Destination Unreachable - Host Administratively Prohibited",
          "0b" : "Destination Unreachable - Network unreachable for TOS",
          "0c" : "Destination Unreachable - Host unreachable for TOS",
          "0d" : "Destination Unreachable - Communication Administratively Prohibited"
     },
     "04": {"00": "Source Quench"},
     "05": {
          "00": "Redirect - Datagram for the Network",
          "01": "Redirect - Datagram for the Host",
          "02": "Redirect - Datagram for the TOS & Network",
          "03": "Redirect - Datagram for the TOS & Host"
     },
     "08":{"00": "Echo " },
     "09":{"00": "Router Advertisement"},
     "0a": {"00": "Router Selection" },
     "0b": {
          "01":"Time Exceeded - Time to live exceeded in Transit",
          "02":"Time Exceeded - Fragment Reassembly Time Exceeded"
     },
     "0c": {
         "00": "Parameter Problem - Pointer indicates the error",
          "01": "Parameter Problem - Missing a Required Option",
          "02": "Parameter Problem - Bad Length"
     },
     "0d": {"00": "Timestamp" },
     "0e": {"00": "Timestamp Reply" },
     "0f": {"00": "Information Request"},
     "10": {"00": "Information Reply"},
     "11": {"00": "Address Mask Request"},
     "12": {"00": "Address Mask Reply"},
     "1e": {"00": "Traceroute"}
}
```